# Remove & replace characters using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe and would like to remove all the brackets and replace with two hyphens.

Before:

```
+------------+
|  dob_concat|
+------------+
|[1983][6][3]|
+------------+
```

After:

```
+------------+
| dob_concat |
+------------+
| 1983-6-3   |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `regexp_replace` inbuilt function as below.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("dob_concat", F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace("dob_concat", "\\]\\[", "-"), "\\[", ""), "\\]", "")).show()
```